# Dog scratches on door frames

Tags: door-frame

[image]I’m moving out of my apartment in 6 weeks and have started assessing the damage of 6 years total, two years with a rescue dog that took some time adjusting. She scratched at a lot of the doors when she was anxious and alone.

What can I do to fix these spots? I feel like sanding and wood filler, but I’m not sure? How much should I worry about repainting if he has to repaint anyway before the new tenants.

Comment: With paint your solution will work well.  If it was stained/natural looking wood trim then it would be much harder.

Comment: You should paint anyway even if the landlord will be painting between tenants.  It will be easier to see if your filler repair was good or not.

Comment: Thank you!! I will be posting more questions! Because there are some claw marks in the hardwood at a different door. Should I get a professional for that?